# How can I get this paragraph 1 to look like paragraph 2 .. any shortcut ? don't want to edit manually

Tags: ms-word, editing

How can I get this paragraph 1 to look like paragraph 2 .. any shortcuts in word ? don't want to edit manually, don't know what to do. That is everything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12quG.png)

### I edit it manually.. don't want that , dont know what to do .. please help me

Comment: What is "look like"? what do you mean? Do you mean the format? The number of words per line, the length of each line? Could me give me a sample to do?

Comment: Apply a style or use the Format Painter. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm Tthis is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. Add link in your question here to the new question to help others.